# MySQL How to use DISTINCT value with associated id

Tags: mysql, distinct

Take an example I have mySQL table as:

```
id           Name
1             Abc
2             Abc
3             Xyz
4             Xyz
5             Abc
```

Now I want the reult to get:

```
id        Name
1          Abc
3          Xyz
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't looking for `distinct`, but rather `group by`.  You can use the `min` aggregate for this:

```
select min(id), name
from yourtable
group by name
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c9ea/1)